# OpenApi 3 import schemas from external files

Tags: rest, web-services, xsd, swagger, openapi

I am defining common schemas for Web services and I want to import them in the components/schema section of the specification.
I want to create a canonical data model that is common across multiple services to avoid redefining similar objects in each service definition.

Is there a way to do this?
Is there a similar mechanism to what XSD does with its import tag?

Answer (score 17, accepted):

You can `$ref` external OpenAPI schema objects directly using absolute or relative URLs:

```yaml
responses:
  '200':
    description: OK
    schema:
      $ref: './common/Pet.yaml'
      # or
      # $ref: 'https://api.example.com/schemas/Pet.yaml'
```

where Pet.yaml contains, for example:

```
type: object
properties:
  id:
    type: integer
    readOnly: true
  petType:
    type: string
  name:
    type: string
required:
  - id
  - petType
  - name
```

See [Using $ref](https://swagger.io/docs/specification/using-ref/) for more information.

Answer (score 19):

To expand on Helen's answer for those landing here from Google, if Pet.yaml is not a plain object but has several objects like this:

```
components:
  schemas:
    pet:
      type: object
      properties:
        (...)
```

You can refer to it like this:

```
$ref: './common/Pet.yaml#/components/schemas/pet'
```

Comment: But what if I want to include a document instead of referencing a document? There is a difference. I don't want to click. This problem has also been addressed within XML (XLink). I was hoping to see something similar in the OpenAPI standard.

Comment: What do you mean by "I don't want to click"?